# Using Mist or Depth pass to create a color-specific mist

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a base scene with objects retreating in the distance:
[image]

The background color is created in the World properties using a background color.

I also have Mist and Depth passes enabled. Here is Mist:
[image]

I composite them together to get:
[image]

using this node set-up:
[image]

My goal -- which I have not been able to achieve using the various passes I have thus far -- is to make the mist pass (or Depth, or whatever will get me there)  darken and obscure objects as they recede in the distance and to do so by making the 'mist' a darker color -- darker green/blue in this case...

The objective is for further objects to be less visible and to be obscured with the some version of the background color, not grayishness, and to go this in the compositor.

All input welcome.

[image]

Comment: Part of the problem is that you have a colorless sun light killing all of the color on the far away cubes. Get rid of it or make it the color of the other light or background https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF3Ey.png